# Aggregate Count Array Members Matching Condition

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I'm having some trouble, as stated in title, to count elements in an Array using MongoDB.
I have a DB with only one document, made as follow:

```
 {_id: ObjectId("abcdefghilmnopq"),
    "Array": [
      {field1: "val1",
       field2: "val2",
       field3: "val3",
       ...
       },
       {field1: "Value1",
        field2: "Value2",
        field3: "Value3",
       ...
       },
        ...
     ]
 }
```

I wanna count the number of elements of the array which have a certain condition (e.g. `field1: "a"`, and count all elements which have `field1 = a`).
I'm trying with this code:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
{ $unwind : {path: "$Array", 
             includeArrayIndex: "arrayIndex"}},
{ $match : { "Array.field1" : "a"}},
{ $project : { _id : 0, 
               Array : 1, 
               arrayIndex: 1, 
               total: {$size: "$Array"}}}
])
```

but I receive this error:

> Command failed with error 17124: 'The argument to $size must be an
> array, but was of type: object' on server

I looked for several answer to this problem, but I didn't find anything resolutive for my problem. I mean, 'Array' IS an array!

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The error is because it's no longer an array after you [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and therefore no longer a valid argument to [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/).

You appear to be attempting to "merge" a couple of existing answers without understanding what they are doing. What you really want here is [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "total": {
      "$size": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$Array",
          "cond": { "$eq": [ "$$this.field1", "a" ] }
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Or "reinvent the wheel" using [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/):

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "total": {
      "$reduce": {
        "input": "$Array",
        "initialValue": 0,
        "in": {
          "$sum": [
            "$$value", 
            { "$cond": [{ "$eq": [ "$$this.field1", "a" ] }, 1, 0] }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Or for what you were trying to do with [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/), you actually [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) again in order to "count" how many matches there were:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$unwind": "$Array" },
  { "$match": { "Array.field1": "a" } },
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "total": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
])
```

The first two forms are the "optimal" for modern MongoDB environments. The final form with [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) and [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) is a "legacy" construct which really has not been necessary for this type of operation since MongoDB 2.6, though with some slightly different operators.

In those first two we are basically comparing the `field1` value of each array element whilst it's still an array. Both [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) and [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/) are modern operators designed to work with an existing array in place. The same comparison is done on each one using the aggregation [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) operator which returns a boolean value based on whether the arguments given are "equal" or not. In this case on each array member to the expected value of `"a"`.

In the case of [`$filter`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/filter/), the array actually remains intact except for any elements which did not meet the supplied condition in `"cond"` are removed from the array. Since we still have an "array" as output we can then use the [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator to measure the number of array elements left after that filter condition was processed.

The [`$reduce`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) on the other hand works through the array elements and supplies an expression over each element and a stored "accumulator" value, which we initialized with `"initialValue"`. In this case the same [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) test is applied within the [`$cond`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/cond/) operator. This is a "ternary" or `if/then/else` conditional operator which allows a tested expression which returns a boolean value to return the `then` value when `true` or the `else` value when `false`.

In that expression we return `1` or `0` respectively and supply the overall result of adding that returned value and the current "accumulator" `"$$value"` with the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) operator to add these together.

The final form used [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) on the array. What this actually does is deconstructs the array members to create a "new document" for every array member and it's related parent fields in the original document. This effectively "copies" the main document for every array member.

Once you [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the structure of the documents is changed to a "flatter" form. This is why you can then do the subsequent [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline stage to remove the un-matched documents.

This brings us to [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) which is applied to "bring back together" all of the information related to a common key. In this case it's the `_id` field of the original document, which was of course copied into every document produced by the [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/). As we go back to this "common key" as a single document, we can "count" the remaining "documents" extracted from the array using the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) accumulator.

If we wanted the remaining "array" back, then you can [`$push`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/push/) and rebuild the array with only the remaining members:

```
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "Array": { "$push": "$Array" },
    "total": { "$sum": 1 }
  }}
```

But of course instead of using [`$size`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) in another pipeline stage, we can simply still "count" like we already did with the [`$sum`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/)

Comment: You coudn't explain it better! NOW I got it, i'm new to MongoDB and NoSQL in general, I'm learning all methods and operators little at a time: I didn't know the $unwind (neither $group) mechanism. Really really really thanks!

Comment: This answer is amazing! Thanks Neil!